# Liferay PHP portlet $_POST and $_GET are not working?

Tags: php, liferay, liferay-6

I am using Liferay 6.2( tomcat-7.0.42) bundle ... i think that there is an issue with the URL when directing .... 
and i have no idea about the php quercus libraries

can any one help .... !!?

i have reviewed all the tutorial in the forum :

https://www.liferay.com/community/wiki/-/wiki/Main/How+to+create+a+simple+php+portlet

and github files :

https://github.com/liferay/liferay-plugins/tree/master/portlets/sample-php-portlet

Answer (score 0):

Hi had the same issue,

try putting the portlet prefix to the parameter. Say you are trying with php portlet sample.

`Foo: <input name="_SamplePHP_WAR_samplephpportlet_foo" type="text" value="<?php echo $_GET["foo"]?$_GET["foo"]:$_POST["foo"]; ?>">`

Will make the trick.

Good Luck